# php and stored procedures where the error am I doing?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
$b = mysql_query("CALL dene($sehir)");
$sorgu = mysql_fetch_row($b);
return $sorgu[6];
}

$h=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firmalar");
while($r=mysql_fetch_row($h)){
echo kadir($r[10]);
}
```

Why does a record that I created here in sp?
After the first record from the error.

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\wamp\www.\deneme.php on
>   line 9

Comment: What's your stored procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that one of these lines

```
$sorgu = mysql_fetch_row($b);
$h=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firmalar");
```

is returning `false`

Check what error you get when you change these lines:

```
$b = mysql_query("CALL dene($sehir)") or die(mysql_error()) ;
$h=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firmalar") or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

You say that the response is:

> ISTANBULCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now

It sounds like that the contents of `$sehir` are being interpreted as a command. Maybe it is because (I think) the `$sehir` might have to be enclosed by `'`, so you need to use instead of this:

```
b = mysql_query("CALL dene($sehir)");
```

this:

```
b = mysql_query("CALL dene('$sehir')");
```

Comment: SELECT
         ulke.ulke_no,
         ulke.ulke_adi,
         ulke.ulke_telefon_kodu,
         il.il_id,
         il.il_ulke_no,
         il.il_no,
         il.il_adi
        FROM
              il
        Inner Join ulke ON il.il_ulke_no = ulke.ulke_no
    WHERE il.il_id=e;

Comment: $b = mysql_query("CALL dene($sehir)") or die(mysql_error()) ;
$h=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firmalar") or die(mysql_error()) ;
When I run this way the error I get from.       İSTANBULCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: well, that's the problem. is 'ISTANBUL' in your $sehir var?

Comment: yes there is, no matter which city is the first record. Googlede'm sorry English is not much to English

Comment: added a suggestion of using '`' to the answer.